# How to override the find_by method then call the original in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to override the find_by_ method in my model...
Then inside it I want to call the original + some additional code.

```
class User < Activerecord::Base
  def self.find_by_email(email)
    binding.pry
    super.find_by_email(email) || find_by_social_identities_email(email)
  end
...

end
```

Any ideas are welcome????

Comment: In the definition you could use a `.where(:email => email).first` method.

Comment: Use Ruby Racer's approach. The dynamic "find_by_*" methods uses some trickery involving `method_missing` so it doesnt work like regular methods. That's probably why calling it on `super` fails.

Comment: I realized that find_by_... will create a method find_by_email for the first time so... That inside it I called find_by('email = :email', {email: email}) which is almost Ruby Racer's proposal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I did this way:

```
class User < Activerecord::Base
  def self.find_by_email(email)
    super.find_by('email = :email', {email: email}) || find_by_social_identities_email(email)
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: I believe this could be simplified to `find_by(email: email) || find_by_social_identities_email(email)`

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 5, I needed to use `self` instead of `super`. So that it becomes:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def self.find_by_email(email)
    self.find_by('email = :email', {email: email}) || find_by_social_identities_email(email)
  end
  ...
end
```